# qnamaker doesn't apply changes in knowledgebase

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

I have built a chatbot which uses a qna. Everything works fine. The bot can answer questions specified in the qna. Now i made some changes to the knowledgebase - added some new question/answer pairs and removed some pairs. I saved, trained and published (successfully) like i always did. But my chatbot is still answering questions which has been removed and is not able to answer the new questions.

In the azure portal there is a search service which provides a search explorer. Using this explorer i can search the qna dataset. I does NOT include the changes which has been published successfully.

Settings like EndpointKey, KnowledgebaseId are set properly.

Does anyone have an idea what's going on here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please try deleting the existing KB and upload again. Also, check if your search index limits has exceeded.

Comment: Tanks. I will try that later this day.

Comment: My solution was a bit different but maybe it is the same at last. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my Azure Search Service there were two indexes - one for production, the other for testing. Let's name them "prod" and "test" for simplicity.

**First**: 
Backup the scheme of both indexes using the REST API as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/searchservice/get-index). Then backup your qna pairs in the settings section in your qnamaker.ai. There is an export button where you can download all pairs as an tsv-file.

Now, [delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/searchservice/delete-index) both indexes in Azure Search Service und rea[create](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/searchservice/create-index) them. Then import the tsv-file in qnamaker.ai in the settings section. Save and train, then publish your knowledgebase.

It is important that both indexes are created **before** you publish the KB the first time. Otherwise only the test index will contain the documents.

I'm not sure whether or not deleting the knowlegdebase in qnamaker would also solve the problem. If yes, let me know in the comment.

Comment: Since the KBs are linked in the search indexes in the Search Service, deleting a KB will also delete the index. However, if the index link is corrupted you might not be able to delete the KB from the QnAMaker portal. In that case you can delete the indexes and reupload the KBs. Also, you should note the index count in the Search Service. You might (in some case) end up with multiple indexes if you keep uploading multiple KBs to the same KB ID and run out of the limit. So it is better to edit the knowledge base or recreate it entirely for new updates.

Comment: Good to know. I am still new to the whole Azure thing. Thanks.